# Adjust image size based on the font size

Tags: html, css, image

I am putting together an HTML page to be viewed in both mobile phones and PC/Mac. In the text, I sometimes have inline images:

```
<p>to do that, then press on button <img src="button.png" /> for 2 seconds</p>
```

My fonts are sized in em or % so it is readable on both low res-phones and high-res phones. The issue is that my buttons (usually 32px high images) appear so tiny on high-res phones.

How do I adjust the image size? Preferably pure CSS, but JS is still OK.

Comment: If your paragraph is only going to be single line, set its line height to 32px (in ems), then set the images width to auto and height to 100%. This should, in theory, scale your images as the font size changes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you set the size of your font in the `<p>` tag, you should just be able to use `height: 1em;` on `p img` to set the image's height to that of the font.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GXAE/) to show what I mean:

```css
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  /*sets 1em to 10px for convenience*/
}

p {
  font-size: 3em;
}

p img {
  height: 1em;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello world! <img src="http://images.wikia.com/dragonvale/images/e/e8/Space_invader.jpg"></p>
```

And if you want it to be double the size of the font, you'd just set the height of the image to 2em.

Comment: thanks, that is so simple I am blaming myself to have even ask, I should have find it out :(

Comment: You're welcome! ems are difficult to wrap your head around sometimes, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can give all your images a class and apply the following css rule

```
<p>to do that, then press on button <img class="scale" src="button.png" /> for 2 seconds</p>

.scale
{
    height: 1em; 
    width: 1em;
}
```