# CSS HTML Making pictures depending on font size

Tags: html, css

So I make my font size in vw and I read that if I make my img size in rem they will be dependent on the font size but no its not like that the text go smaller but pictures stay the same :/
Im new to html/css sorry for the question

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but adding a size of an element like an image, or a text in em or vw or px won't automatically make it react to text size as far as i know.
You will most likely need some JS for this to work, which "checks" the font size, and accordingly sets the size of an image.
Tell me if i didn't understand your question correctly. And please also add an example of whatever you did, as Josef mentioned.

Comment: I think you are looking for this?
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435866/7262739](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18435866/7262739)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is that you're using `rem` and not `em`. `rem` refers to root `em`, meaning the font size of the root element. `em` simply refers to the font size of the parent element. If you're trying to change an image's size depending on the font size, I would recommend using `em` over `rem`.